# How to recursively use macros from xstring?

Tags: expansion, xstring

I don't understand why the following mwe throws an errow `TeX capacity exceeded`. I'm guessing there's some expansion issue, but my TeX knowledge is not enough to resolve it.

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{xstring}

\begin{document}
\IfStrEqCase*{\StrBehind*{01}{0}}{{1}{one}{2}{two}}

\end{document}
```

While creating the mwe I noticed that the presence of `\usepackage{siunitx}` changes the error, to many instances of `! Use of \reserved@a doesn't match its definition.` instead. I'm using the starred version of the macros from xstring because I need to in my actual usage.

Comment: \StrBehind is not expandable, you cannot nest it in there